# Does hiding site title and/or tagline or site description matter SEO?

Tags: css, seo

In several tutorial I found that, site title and site description is important for SEO. Even some of 'em uses `<h2>` for site title and `<h1>` for site description grab Search Engines' attention into the website matters.

```
<header>

<div id="logo"><a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo of the Company" title="Company Title"/></a></div>

<hgroup>
<h2 id="site-title">Site Title</h2>
<h1 id="site-description">Site Description</h1>            
</hgroup>

</header>
```

**OPTION I:** But in some web pages, we don't see any site title or description, but a site logo. In that case, designers recommend to use a `text-indent` to hide them.

```
#site-title,
#site-description{
    text-indent: -9999px;
    }
```

It'll hide the texts by indenting 'em from the visible portion, so then the search engine will crawl 'em and it'd be SEO-friendly. But the problem is, they are taking the space in the header section. To meet-up the space we need to put margin to the following items, and that's not a good solution for me.

**OPTION II:** Beside that, we can use `visibility:hidden`

```
#site-title,
#site-description{
    visibility: hidden;
    }
```

I don't know whether it enables the crawler to crawl those texts, but the same problem here too, it's taking the place.

**OPTION III:** But the only thing useful is `display: none` and it works like a pure HTML commenting (`<!-- commented out -->`)

```
#site-title,
#site-description{
    display: none;
    }
```

But truly, it simply vanishes the texts, I think even from the eye of the crawler. So, to me, it's not SEO-friendly.

So, Option I and II is useful with the place-taking problem.

- How can I put 'em there for SE-Crawler, but invisible from the eye without taking place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [**CSS `clip` Property**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp) is a nicely clean and non-conflicting solution to this issue.

```
    h1#site-title,
    h2#site-description{
        position: absolute;
        clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE7 */
        clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
    }
```

> **CSS `clip` Property**
>   The `clip` CSS property defines what portion of an element is visible. The `clip` property applies only to elements with `position:absolute`.

Browser support:
[image: Microsoft Internet Explorer Supported]
[image: Mozilla Firefox Supported]
[image: Opera Supported]
[image: Google Chrome Supported]
[image: Apple Safari Supported]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `display:none` vanishes your code from the source. It is still present there and the search engines will still crawl them.

Try to **inspect the element** (Chrome developer tools or Firebug) or **view source** of your page and you'll see! *CSS never affects the kind of HTML rendered* on the page! It just affects the way it looks. So, relax and use the `display:none` property.

Answer (score 0):

So, here I got the correct answer:
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/how-bad-is-it-to-use-display-none-in-css

We can use `display:none;` and search engine will crawl it, so no tension with SEO.

But **CAUTION:** ***DO NOT USE `display: none;` FOR SPAMMING. :)***

Thank you @akash4eva.